# jQuery Sortable - Keep it in original list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Does anyone know if jQuery UI's Sortable has built-in functionality to keep the original dropped item in it's original list?

For example, you have two lists (one 'source' and one 'group').  I'd like to select from the source and drop into the group, but keep the item in the source.

Make sense?

Thank you!

Answer (score 27):

You can [see my solution in action on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B5PH4/). I simply amended [this jQuery draggable/droppable interaction](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable) to suit your needs.

**HTML**

```
<div class="demo">
    <h2>List 1</h2>
    <ul>
        <li class="draggable ui-state-highlight">Drag me down</li>
        <li class="draggable ui-state-highlight">Drag me down</li>
    </ul>
    <h2>List 2</h2>
    <ul id="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        revert: true
    });
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        connectToSortable: "#sortable",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid"
    });
    $("ul, li").disableSelection();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.demo ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 20px; }
.demo li { margin: 5px; padding: 5px; width: 150px; border: 1px solid black; }
```

Comment: I'm just passing through.. +1 for a nice little demo and clean solution.

Comment: Like this alot, is there something Im missing though when it comes to getting rid of a cloned item?  I'd imagine they just move it back to the list it originated from but would be good if it didn't show duplicates.

Comment: @daveomcd have you found a way to remove the cloned item ?

Comment: @Helpha, I have not, it is removed on refresh though when I refresh my list so when I get time I'm going to look at refreshing the partial (I'm using rails) that displays the list.  But for now I just leave the duplicates as they are.

Comment: perfect solution for my problem thanks a lot