# jQuery UI sortable: Move clone but keep original

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Right now I have a column of elements and I have it to the point where where I drag, it clones but when I drop, it removes the original as well.

```
$( ".column" ).sortable({
        helper: 'clone',
        connectWith: ".column",
        connectWith: ".grid",
        start: function(e, ui){
            ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
             $(".column" ).find('.portlet:hidden').show()
             console.log('started')
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.helper).clone(true).removeClass('box ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging').addClass('box-clone').appendTo('body');
        }
    });
```

How can I keep the original where its at (without re-appending it to the column) and have the clone move to the desired location?

Comment: Beware of generating invalid HTML (duplicate IDs) when using `clone()`.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940390/how-do-i-duplicate-item-when-using-jquery-sortable) is very similar and has a great answer -- look at the top-voted one, not the accepted one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `$(this).sortable('cancel')` inside the stop event handler to revert the item back to it's original list/position. http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-cancel

```
$( ".column" ).sortable({
        helper: 'clone',
        connectWith: ".column",
        connectWith: ".grid",
        start: function(e, ui){
            ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
             $(".column" ).find('.portlet:hidden').show()
             console.log('started')
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.helper).clone(true).removeClass('box ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging').addClass('box-clone').appendTo('body');
            $(this).sortable('cancel');
        }
    });
```

**UPDATE:**

To append the element to the second list in the location the item was dropping, do something *like* the following:

```
stop: function(event, ui) {
            var toListID = ui.item.parent().attr('id');   
            var idx = $('#' + toListID).children().index($(ui.item[0]));
            if(idx== -1)return;
            var elm = $(ui.item[0]).clone(true).removeClass('box ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging').addClass('box-clone');
            $('#' + toListID).children(':eq('+idx+')').after(elm);
            $(this).sortable('cancel');
        }
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamb/tZSN7/12/) for full demo

Comment: This seems so cancel the cloned element. When I drop, nothing goes into the drop location.

Comment: I see what you're thinking now, I tried that solution before to append but it needs to be in the location of the actual drop. Not just added to the bottom. Any ideas on how to avoid appending?

Comment: For jQuery < 1.8, you might have to  use `$('.list2').children().eq(idx).after(elm);`.  I think this is slightly more efficient as well (according to the docs).

Comment: Thanks so much for the update with an explicit example for copy to specified location! Most helpful!

Comment: @adamb theres a problem with your fiddle. thats when you move items up and down in list1, they are duplicated in list2, regardless of whether you drag them there or not. how do you prevent that?

Comment: Seems that you have a duplicate `connectWith` property in $.fn.sortable definition.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone using new version just use:

```
revert: true
```

More details here: [jQuery Sortable - Keep it in original list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669039/jquery-sortable-keep-it-in-original-list/7209451)

Comment: Thank you so much you made my day. I got what I needed