# jQuery Sortable Drag and Drop - Select Multiple Items and Keep Originals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to set up a jQuery Sortable that will both a) allow for selection of multiple items, and b) once dragged and dropped - ***keep the original items*** in their list. I have the multiple item selection part down, but I cannot get the items to persist in their original box.

I have set up an example of what I have so far on JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/ncsujenn/hQnWG/2518/

In this example you should be able to drag over multiple pizza toppings at a time onto a pizza. Pizza 1, 2 and 3 should all be able to have Pepperoni and Sausage - but the toppings disappear from the list after one use. So once Pizza 1 has Pepperoni and Sausage, Pizza 2 has no choice but to pick veggies.

HTML

```
<ul id="pizzas">
  <li>Pizza 1</li>
  <li>Pizza 2</li>
  <li>Pizza 3</li>
</ul>
<ul id="toppings">
  <li class="draggable">Pepperoni</li>
  <li class="draggable">Sausage</li>
  <li class="draggable">Mushrooms</li>
  <li class="draggable">Olives</li>
  <li class="draggable">Onion</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$("ul").on('click', 'li', function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass('selected');
  }
});

$("#pizzas, #toppings").sortable({
  connectWith: "#pizzas",
  delay: 150, 
  revert: 0,
  helper: function(e, item) {
    //Manage selection class
    if (!item.hasClass('selected')) {
      item.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    }
    var elements = item.parent().children('.selected').clone();
    item.data('multidrag', elements).siblings('.selected').remove();
    var helper = $('<li/>');
    return helper.append(elements);
  },
  stop: function(e, ui) {
    //Get stored multi selected items
    var elements = ui.item.data('multidrag');
    // Handle duplicates in receiving box
    ui.item.after(elements).remove();
  }

}).disableSelection();
```

CSS

```
ul {
  border: 1px solid Black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top
}

li {
  background-color: Azure;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted Gray
}

li.selected {
  background-color: GoldenRod
}

#toppings {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an existing question & answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7209451/203172

Review the [api documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/) specifically the [helper](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper) option which will allow you to clone the toppings.